# How to import an excel file into a database table as binary type by using SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, excel

I have an excel file. I just would like to import the excel file into a table ExcelFiles without using c# code.

ExcelFiles has 3 columns

```
ExcelId, ExcelName,    ExcelFile
int       varchar(50),  varbinary(max)
```

I would like to import excel file into this table through SQL Server Management Studio without using c#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO ExcelFiles
(ExcelId, ExcelName, ExcelFile)
SELECT 1, 'filename', * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'C:\filename.xslx', SINGLE_BLOB) rs
```